# Pandas: Always selecting the first sheet/tab in an Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I know how to get the list of sheet names. The excel file I am using has multiple sheets. How do I select the first one sequentially ? I don't know the name of the sheet but I need to select the first one. How would I go about this ?

Comment: [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) the `sheetname` param defaults to `0` which is the first sheet

Comment: even if there are multiple sheets it selects the first one ?

Comment: Yes, why don't you try it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first sheet is automatically selected when the Excel table is read into a dataframe.

To be explicit however, the command is :

```
import pandas as pd
fd = 'file path'
data = pd.read_excel( fd, sheet_name=0 )
```

Use of 'sheetname' is deprecated. Please use sheet_name

Answer (score 2):

Also this bug at the time of writing:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17107

Use 'sheetname', not 'sheet_name'.

Comment: Thanks @RGH !!! I was going crazy not knowing what I was doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and as already suggested by EdChum, it's enough to use read_excell passing sheetname=N as argument.
N=0 for the first sheet, N=1 for the second, N=2 for the third and so on..

Comment: You don't even need to pass the sheet name, you can simply leave out the `sheetname` or `sheet_name` (the former is depreciated as of this writing) and it will take the first